# How to separate EEG frequency band in python?

Tags: signal-analysis, python, power-spectral-density, eeg

Sorry for stupid question! I am very new in EEG signal processing and python environment.I have started my a project work related to EEG signal analysis using MNE. I would like to  separate EEG Bands  using bandpass filter. For this purpose I did the below coding to separate EEG Bands by following some of MNE tutorial:

```
iter_freqs = [
    ('Theta', 4, 7),
    ('Alpha', 8, 12),
    ('Beta', 13, 25),
    ('Gamma', 30, 50)                                                                                                                                                     for band, fmin, fmax in iter_freqs:
    raw_filt = raw_temp.copy()
    data, times = raw_filt[0]
 # bandpass filter
    raw_filt.filter(fmin, fmax, n_jobs=1,  
               l_trans_bandwidth=1, 
               h_trans_bandwidth=1)
```

Now I would like to plot power of  each frequency  separately.I could not make sence how I will do this.I will appreciate if some one help me in this regard.

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: Soory ! Now i edited my question

Comment: I am not familiar with the MNE library but if you are able to plot the waveforms in the time domain after filtering, I could help you.

Comment: @DanBoschen,that would be a great help.It is not mandatory for me to use MNE .

Comment: the relative power spectral density in dB can be plotted using 10log(|fft|^2), where fft is the fft of your time domain sequence. Zero pad your sequence if you want to interpolate more values in frequency.  You can use scipy.fftpack to do the fft in python. I hope that helps you!

Answer (score 1):

import mne

plot.psd()

this is the function for calculating power spectral dimension of your eeg signal.